# Hi there. I have a problem with uniform convergence of functional series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio, conditional-convergence

I have no idea what to do and how to start even, please give some pieces of advice. And if you can solve this task I will be very thankful
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt[]{n^{3}+1}},\quad x\in (-\infty; \infty)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{\sqrt{n^{3}+1}}\leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$
Then use [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

We know that

$$(\forall n\in \mathbb N)\;(\forall x\in\mathbb R)\;\;\;|\sin (nx)|\leq 1$$

$$\implies (\forall n>0) \; (\forall x\in \mathbb R)$$ $$\;\;|u_n (x)|\leq \frac {1}{n^{3/2}} $$

$$\implies (\forall n>0) \;\;\sup_{\mathbb R}|u_n(x)|\leq \frac {1}{n^{3/2}} $$
the series $\sum u_n (x) $ is normally and then uniformly convergent at $\mathbb R$.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your help.